# can't access apps on nokia lumia 520

Tags: apps

Why do I suddenly loose access to the apps I have downloaded? It started with Trivia Crack, and now Facebook. There are no required updates pending.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose access"? Are the apps gone or are they crashing?

Comment: The Facebook app that is pinned to my home screen is greyed out. When I click on it, it does not open. When I try to open it from the app screen, it does not open either. The same thing happened with Trivia Crack first, but I just uninstalled it. So I guess they are crashing?

Comment: Is there enough memory to install app ??

Comment: I think these apps were stored in sd card. reinsert the sd card.

Comment: I don't have/never had a SD card.

Comment: It has been installed since I got the phone. It is the first app I installed. My phone contacts and calendar are all linked to fb. If memory gets low, can that disable an app that is already installed?

Comment: The phone should manage the memory without needing you to step in. Can you check if perhaps an update is stuck in the store?

Comment: How long has it been like this? Twitter does that for me quite frequently, but always fixes itself eventually. Have you tried reinstalling the app?

Comment: Funny you should ask that. It was almost three days. When I just checked my email, there was fb. Problem seemed to resolve itself. Maybe I was just overworking it and it needed a break. 

Comment: I update as soon as I get a notification from the store icon. It seems to have been a temporary glitch. Facebook is back. Thank you everyone for your insight. Best help forum I have ever used!